# TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined | ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm getting error *TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined*. I'm just following the freeCodeCamps's guide on YouTube called "React Tutorial: Build an e-commerce site from scratch using React and Netlify". I'm copying all the code so that it's identical. I wonder what might be causing this issue.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Product from "./Product";
import Title from "./Title";
import { storeProducts } from "../data";
import { ProductConsumer } from "../context";

class ProductList extends Component {
  state = {
    products: storeProducts
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <div className="py-5">
          <div className="container">
            <Title name="our" title="products" />

            <div className="row">
              <ProductConsumer>
                {value => {
                  return value.products.map(product => {
                    return <Product key={product.id} product={product} />;
                  });
                }}
              </ProductConsumer>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}

export default ProductList;
```

Here's the rest of the files:

*context.js*

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { storeProducts, detailProduct } from "./data";

const ProductContext = React.createContext();
//Provider
//Consumer

class ProductProvider extends Component {
  state = {
    products: storeProducts,
    detailProduct: detailProduct
  };
  handleDetail = () => {
    console.log("hello from detail");
  };
  addToCart = () => {
    console.log("hello from addToCart");
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <ProductContext.Provider
        value={{
          ...this.state,
          handleDetail: this.handleDetail,
          addToCart: this.addToCart
        }}
      >
        {this.props.children}
      </ProductContext.Provider>
    );
  }
}

const ProductConsumer = ProductContext.Consumer;

export { ProductProvider, ProductConsumer };
```

*product.js*

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class Product extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h3>This is a product</h3>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Product;
```

*data.js*

```
/* 
https://www.iconfinder.com/icons/1243689/call_phone_icon
Creative Commons (Attribution 3.0 Unported);
https://www.iconfinder.com/Makoto_msk */

export const storeProducts = [
  {
    id: 1,
    title: "Google Pixel - Black",
    img: "img/product-1.png",
    price: 10,
    company: "GOOGLE",
    info:
      "Lorem ipsum dolor amet offal butcher quinoa sustainable gastropub, echo park actually green juice sriracha paleo. Brooklyn sriracha semiotics, DIY coloring book mixtape craft beer sartorial hella blue bottle. Tote bag wolf authentic try-hard put a bird on it mumblecore. Unicorn lumbersexual master cleanse blog hella VHS, vaporware sartorial church-key cardigan single-origin coffee lo-fi organic asymmetrical. Taxidermy semiotics celiac stumptown scenester normcore, ethical helvetica photo booth gentrify.",
    inCart: false,
    count: 0,
    total: 0
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    title: "Samsung S7",
    img: "img/product-2.png",
    price: 16,
    company: "SAMSUNG",
    info:
      "Lorem ipsum dolor amet offal butcher quinoa sustainable gastropub, echo park actually green juice sriracha paleo. Brooklyn sriracha semiotics, DIY coloring book mixtape craft beer sartorial hella blue bottle. Tote bag wolf authentic try-hard put a bird on it mumblecore. Unicorn lumbersexual master cleanse blog hella VHS, vaporware sartorial church-key cardigan single-origin coffee lo-fi organic asymmetrical. Taxidermy semiotics celiac stumptown scenester normcore, ethical helvetica photo booth gentrify.",
    inCart: false,
    count: 0,
    total: 0
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    title: "HTC 10 - Black",
    img: "img/product-3.png",
    price: 8,
    company: "htc",
    info:
      "Lorem ipsum dolor amet offal butcher quinoa sustainable gastropub, echo park actually green juice sriracha paleo. Brooklyn sriracha semiotics, DIY coloring book mixtape craft beer sartorial hella blue bottle. Tote bag wolf authentic try-hard put a bird on it mumblecore. Unicorn lumbersexual master cleanse blog hella VHS, vaporware sartorial church-key cardigan single-origin coffee lo-fi organic asymmetrical. Taxidermy semiotics celiac stumptown scenester normcore, ethical helvetica photo booth gentrify.",
    inCart: false,
    count: 0,
    total: 0
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    title: "HTC 10 - White",
    img: "img/product-4.png",
    price: 18,
    company: "htc",
    info:
      "Lorem ipsum dolor amet offal butcher quinoa sustainable gastropub, echo park actually green juice sriracha paleo. Brooklyn sriracha semiotics, DIY coloring book mixtape craft beer sartorial hella blue bottle. Tote bag wolf authentic try-hard put a bird on it mumblecore. Unicorn lumbersexual master cleanse blog hella VHS, vaporware sartorial church-key cardigan single-origin coffee lo-fi organic asymmetrical. Taxidermy semiotics celiac stumptown scenester normcore, ethical helvetica photo booth gentrify.",
    inCart: false,
    count: 0,
    total: 0
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    title: "HTC Desire 626s",
    img: "img/product-5.png",
    price: 24,
    company: "htc",
    info:
      "Lorem ipsum dolor amet offal butcher quinoa sustainable gastropub, echo park actually green juice sriracha paleo. Brooklyn sriracha semiotics, DIY coloring book mixtape craft beer sartorial hella blue bottle. Tote bag wolf authentic try-hard put a bird on it mumblecore. Unicorn lumbersexual master cleanse blog hella VHS, vaporware sartorial church-key cardigan single-origin coffee lo-fi organic asymmetrical. Taxidermy semiotics celiac stumptown scenester normcore, ethical helvetica photo booth gentrify.",
    inCart: false,
    count: 0,
    total: 0
  },
  {
    id: 6,
    title: "Vintage Iphone",
    img: "img/product-6.png",
    price: 17,
    company: "apple",
    info:
      "Lorem ipsum dolor amet offal butcher quinoa sustainable gastropub, echo park actually green juice sriracha paleo. Brooklyn sriracha semiotics, DIY coloring book mixtape craft beer sartorial hella blue bottle. Tote bag wolf authentic try-hard put a bird on it mumblecore. Unicorn lumbersexual master cleanse blog hella VHS, vaporware sartorial church-key cardigan single-origin coffee lo-fi organic asymmetrical. Taxidermy semiotics celiac stumptown scenester normcore, ethical helvetica photo booth gentrify.",
    inCart: false,
    count: 0,
    total: 0
  },
  {
    id: 7,
    title: "Iphone 7",
    img: "img/product-7.png",
    price: 30,
    company: "apple",
    info:
      "Lorem ipsum dolor amet offal butcher quinoa sustainable gastropub, echo park actually green juice sriracha paleo. Brooklyn sriracha semiotics, DIY coloring book mixtape craft beer sartorial hella blue bottle. Tote bag wolf authentic try-hard put a bird on it mumblecore. Unicorn lumbersexual master cleanse blog hella VHS, vaporware sartorial church-key cardigan single-origin coffee lo-fi organic asymmetrical. Taxidermy semiotics celiac stumptown scenester normcore, ethical helvetica photo booth gentrify.",
    inCart: false,
    count: 0,
    total: 0
  },
  {
    id: 8,
    title: "Smashed Iphone",
    img: "img/product-8.png",
    price: 2,
    company: "apple",
    info:
      "Lorem ipsum dolor amet offal butcher quinoa sustainable gastropub, echo park actually green juice sriracha paleo. Brooklyn sriracha semiotics, DIY coloring book mixtape craft beer sartorial hella blue bottle. Tote bag wolf authentic try-hard put a bird on it mumblecore. Unicorn lumbersexual master cleanse blog hella VHS, vaporware sartorial church-key cardigan single-origin coffee lo-fi organic asymmetrical. Taxidermy semiotics celiac stumptown scenester normcore, ethical helvetica photo booth gentrify.",
    inCart: false,
    count: 0,
    total: 0
  }
];

export const detailProduct = {
  id: 1,
  title: "Google Pixel - Black",
  img: "img/product-1.png",
  price: 10,
  company: "google",
  info:
    "Lorem ipsum dolor amet offal butcher quinoa sustainable gastropub, echo park actually green juice sriracha paleo. Brooklyn sriracha semiotics, DIY coloring book mixtape craft beer sartorial hella blue bottle. Tote bag wolf authentic try-hard put a bird on it mumblecore. Unicorn lumbersexual master cleanse blog hella VHS, vaporware sartorial church-key cardigan single-origin coffee lo-fi organic asymmetrical. Taxidermy semiotics celiac stumptown scenester normcore, ethical helvetica photo booth gentrify.",
  inCart: false,
  count: 0,
  total: 0
};
```

Comment: Right before your `.map()` add a `console.log(value)` to see if you're getting the value from the context provider. I don't see anything in your code that immediately jumps out at me as the problem.

Comment: could we see the usage of the provider?

Comment: @ technicallynick, no it actually doesn;t fetch the array from the context provider but oddly a string value that I have used for test purposes but removed a while ago... I first though it's cached or something but no, it's weird...

Answer (score 0):

`value` is undefined because the `ProductProvider` component has not been called to create `ProductContext.Provider`.

You do this by importing `ProductProvider` in your main file to replace `React.Fragment`.